Must a US citizen visting Nicaragua fill out the Solicitud de Ingreso y Egreso?
According to Avianca's document checker, a US citizen visiting Nicaragua for a brief visit for purposes of tourism must fill out the Solicitud de Ingreso y Egreso form in advance of travel. However, Timatic lists no such requirement, while the US State Department splits the difference, saying that non-tourist visitors are recommended (but apparently not required?) to fill out the form.
Which of these sources are right? What do I do if Avianca insists I submit the form but the Nicaraguan govenrment does not care?
I am aware of the separate requirement to have US$10 in cash to pay for a tourist card upon arrival; this question is only about any actions I might need to take before boarding a plane.

Avianca may be wrong, Still, if Avianca says you must have the form, then Avianca may or will not allow you to board unless you have completed the form. Seems to me you can choose to do what Avianca wants, or risk not flying.

I can report that no, the form does not appear to be required as of December 2024; Avianca's website is the one which is wrong.
I did not fill out the online form and no one said a word to me about it, neither at the departure airport nor upon arrival. I do not know what tool Avianca gate agents use but it appears to have this (lack of) a requirement correct, while the public website remains incorrect.

The very website of the interior ministry does NOT state any exemptions to the requirement to have the form completed before travel. So I'd assume that yes, you need to do it.
Worst that can happen is that you didn't need it after all, no harm done (seems to me there is no required payment, it's just an advance notice for border control of who's expected to enter the country).
